# Selenium simple loop but having trouble to implement

Tags: python, selenium

trying to do this on Instagram. there is code before it like importing the libraries and chrome driver path and logging in..so below is the loop that is failing...what's your suggestion? it works when I put in a list of exact URLs..so there is definitely something wrong in the loop

```py
users=['instagramuser1','instagramuser2','instagramuser3']
user=-1
for user in users:
    user+=1
    webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+str(users)+'/')
    sleep(5)
    webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('the_amazing_css_path').click()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. And as `user` is a string, you are trying to `+=1` to a string. Which wouldn't work (obviously).

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
users=['instagramuser1','instagramuser2','instagramuser3']

for user in users:
    webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + user + '/')
    sleep(5)
    webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('the_amazing_css_path').click()
```

Note `user` instead of `users` in the URL string.

Comment: thanks...how do i make it pull from a csv file instead? would this work: users="
C:\Users\Downloads\xyz.csv"

Comment: No, it won't. Read [How to read a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use exact code posted in the question.
so you did not follow python indent rule in this particular code
it sould be fix like this:

```
users=['instagramuser1','instagramuser2','instagramuser3']
for user in users:
    webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+user+'/')
    sleep(5)
    webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('the_amazing_css_path').click()
```